# How to connect Sqoop to multiple hadoop clusters

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Is there anyway to have Sqoop connected to different Hadoop clusters so that multiple Sqoop jobs can be created to export data to multiple hadoop clusters?

Comment: I think Sqoop2 can do that, but Sqoop1 is very much tied to your hdfs configuration files

Comment: @cricket_007 can you point me to some docs regarding how Sqoop2 does it.

Comment: sqoop.apache.org has all the information you need

Comment: I might suggest Nifi instead. It can query databases and put into hdfs. Or SparkSQL, depending on your needs.

Comment: We have NiFi as part of our deployment to hand other data sources. But for Sqoop, since it utilizes the parallelism provided by Hadoop, also it's part of our legacy, we'd like to stick to it when it comes to moving bulk data between RDBMS and Hadoop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to export data to multiple hadoop clusters

If data is going into Hadoop, that's technically a Sqoop import

Not clear how you currently manage different clusters from one machine, but you would need to have the conf folder of all environments available for Sqoop to read

> The sqoop command-line program is a wrapper which runs the `bin/hadoop` script shipped with Hadoop. If you have multiple installations of Hadoop present on your machine, you can select the Hadoop installation by setting the `$HADOOP_HOME` environment variable.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>    $ HADOOP_HOME=/path/to/some/hadoop sqoop import --arguments...
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
>    $ export HADOOP_HOME=/some/path/to/hadoop
>    $ sqoop import --arguments...
> ```
>
> If `$HADOOP_HOME` is not set, Sqoop will use the default installation location for Cloudera’s Distribution for Hadoop, `/usr/lib/hadoop`.
> The active Hadoop configuration is loaded from `$HADOOP_HOME/conf/`, unless the `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` environment variable is set

https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_the_hadoop_installation

Depending on how you setup Hadoop, Hortonworks only has Sqoop 1, while Cloudera (and maybe MapR) have Sqoop2, and those instructions are probably different since Sqoop2 architecture is different.